# How to convert list to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

While converting the list to numpy array gives the error

> `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'array"`

Code:

```
d=np.array(list1)
```

Comment: Has `np` been assigned a value elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Double check your code somewhere you have reassigned a value to `np` . Or try `import numpy ` then use `numpy .array`

Comment: what's in `list1`? is `np` re-assigned?

Comment: Thank, it was mentioned somewhere else, silly one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @venky, check if you are using "np" as a variable somewhere. If not try the code below and see if you get an error. It should work

```
import numpy as np
mylist = [1,2,3]
a = np.array(mylist)
type(a)
```